Long horizon recursive forecasting using XGBoost/Random Forest
I'm currently working on a large-scale time series framework at my job and encountering some frustration when it comes to XGBoost/Random Forest. The goal of this effort is to be able to forecast 18 months in the future, therefore necessitating the addition of recursive forecasting, as I will be doing more than a point forecast.
Unfortunately, even with Optuna, I'm struggling quite a bit to produce long horizon forecasts that are good, even plausible, as the data becomes more and more noisy as you traverse the horizon. I wanted to use this forum as a place to discuss some potential improvements that I could add. I'm tuning the amount of lags to use for autoregression, and also only using the target quantity as the response, no other exogenous or endogenous regressors. Is this something where unfortunately recursive forecasting is necessary or is there a different approach?
I should also include that this framework is responsible for forecasting 20,000 different items, and typical workarounds must be discarded in consideration of computational safety.

You can also tune models directly for long-term forecasts, in the extreme case having one model for 1 month ahead, a different model for 2 months ahead, and so forth. Long-range forecasting is inherently harder. Prediction intervals rather than point forecasts often make more sense. That said, this may be helpful.

Thank you for the response @StephanKolassa ! I should've included that framework is responsible for over 20,000 different datasets, so training 18 models on each item isn't feasible (I have 10 other frameworks apart from XGBoost and Random Forest). It's frustrating because the latter 2 mentioned perform super well on the testing phase, but produce almost nonsensical forecasts.

What is a "dataset" for you? A single time series?

Yes. Demand quantities and demand months, for a single item. Scale that by 20,000

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

OK. If you are running boosting and similar methods, one would usually fit a "global" model. (This is also what most submissions to the M5 competition did, with over 30,000 time series on the bottom level.) If I understand you correctly, you are fitting a separate model to each time series. That does not really leverage the strengths of modern ML methods. Why do you do that?

I figured it suitable as detecting trends and seasonalities is far more sensitive on the granular level of the hierarchy. Are you suggesting fitting a global quantity to an aggregated hierarchy, then hierarchal forecast each item down to the item level?

I see your point. You mean literally fitting a global model, not using a hierarchal forecast

The latter: not modeling on aggregates, but on the granular level, but with a global model, with indicator variables identifying each series. If you have a useful hierarchy, by all means feed that in as more (typically time-invariant) features. Take a look at the M5 competition and the entire special issue of the International Journal of Forecasting devoted to it, if you have access.

Interesting. Thank you for your words - this was profoundly helpful. I'm interested how modeling globally with an ordinal indicator actually increases accuracy.

Have you had a look at how people approach this on Kaggle? There's plenty of examples of having to predict sales for multiple timepoints. I don't think recursive approach (i.e. where you predict one timepoint and then use that prediction as an input to the prediction for the next timepoint) is a common way of doing this. Alternatives include:

Train tree-based model using data up to time x as the input features, but as additional features which day you are predicting (including how far it is in the future, what week day, month etc.). You just end up creating more records from your training data (e.g. predict 10 July 2023 once based on the data incl. 9 July 2023, once based on the data 1 month before that etc., in whatever timesteps make sense). Doing that should even let you get your prediction uncertainty roughly right (predicting further out should usually harder), if you do something like conformal prediction.
Train a model that can output predictions for multiple future times at the same time (e.g. suitable neural networks can do that, but there's many other things, just be aware stuff like Facebook's Prophet have developed a bit of a bad reputation for too often getting beaten by ARIMA).

Also, don't forget to benchmark against something very simple and evaluate properly (e.g. past-vs-future validation set-up) to see whether your complex model is any good.

yes I'm using both NN's and Prophet (Prophet stinks though). these work well. also benchmarking. im specifically pointing to the issue arising in building a 'from-scratch' XGB and Random Forest model, as you have to reformat the data to be a supervised learning problem
